# Can I use HANDLE_MSG message crackers in dialog procedures?

Tags: winapi, dialog

First, I thought `HANDLE_MSG` shouldn’t be used in dialog procedures, because in dialog procedures, if user had processed the message, the dialog procedures should return `TRUE` ([MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms645469.aspx)), but `HANDLE_MSG` returns the message's return value, and for most cases, it’s 0 (like [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd145213.aspx) and [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms647591.aspx)) which is `FALSE`.

But I saw in many cases, people just use it, like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd742750.aspx), and it works fine. I am confused. So, can I use `HANDLE_MSG` in dialog procedures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that example doesn't score a lot of points for clarity.  It however just isn't not very common to return TRUE.  Or that returning FALSE on a message that you actually implemented has any negative side-effects.  Since you usually listen for messages that the default dialog procedure will ignore or whose default implementation is something you want anyway.

You need to avoid flipping the ignore bit and consider for each message what the appropriate return value should be.  And whether or not you need to call SetWindowLong to set DWL_MSGRESULT, the more appropriate use for the HANDLE_MSG return value.  Relying on a macro isn't the right thing to do, macros are not smart enough for that.  It does require a programmer.  So it is fine to use HANDLE_MSG.  But you may well need to add a *return* or SetWindowLong call, depending on the message.